# How to automatically scroll to the bottom of the page, in Chrome, once the page is loaded? (Not on my website, but in general)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I tried to run the following Javascript code with an extension but it doesn't scroll once the page loads.

```
window.onload = function() {
  window.scrollTo(0, document.documentElement.scrollHeight);
};
```

Also, Is it possible to make the page scroll down even when multiple tabs are open and a tab is not in focus?

Thanks.

Found nothing that works yeat.

Comment: This is a method that works, as well, but it's not automatic. The script only works if the tab is in focus. If I open 10 tabs, I want the script to run automatically, without me even going through them. I think what I ask for is impossible. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const scrollingElement = (document.scrollingElement || document.body);

const scrollToBottom = () => {
   scrollingElement.scrollTop = scrollingElement.scrollHeight;
}

const myFunction = () => {
   scrollingElement.scrollTop = scrollingElement.scrollHeight;

}

const scrollToTop = () => {
   scrollingElement.scrollTop = 0;
}

// Require jQuery
const scrollSmoothToBottom = () => {
   $(scrollingElement).animate({
      scrollTop: document.body.scrollHeight,
   }, 500);
}

// Require jQuery
const scrollSmoothToTop = () => {
   $(scrollingElement).animate({
      scrollTop: 0,
   }, 500);
}
```

```css
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: visible;
}
#div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: orange;
}

span {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body onload="myFunction()">

<button onClick="scrollToBottom()">Scroll to Bottom</button>
<button onClick="scrollSmoothToBottom()">Scroll <b>smoothly</b> to Bottom</button>
<hr />
<span>Top of Body</span>

<!-- body content -->
<div id="div">
  Body Content
</div>

<span>Bottom of Body</span>
<hr />
<button onClick="scrollToTop()">Scroll to Top</button>
<button onClick="scrollSmoothToTop()">Scroll <b>smoothly</b> to Top</button>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I want it to automatically scroll, by itself, once the page is done loading.

Comment: I made an edit i think it should be okay now.

Comment: This works, if I implement it on my website. In my initial question, I stated: (Not on my website, but in general). I want chrome to load said script on any website I visit. I could simply use something like:  `code` window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight); `code` and it would take me to the bottom, but only if the current tab is in focus. So I want a website to automatically scroll to the bottom regardless if the tab is in focus or not. But I don't think this is possible. I searched for days.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).